# My console is printing random words as well as not performing the right math

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a simple math question program. The program gets 3 random numbers. The first two are the numbers used in the math question. The third one determines what type of problem it is(add, subtract, multiply). However, when I try to check if the user input is equal to the answer, the answer is not equal to what it should be. The console also prints some weird stuff, I've attached a link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N75tX.jpg
Here's text of what the console outputs after another run:

```
Welcome to the math tutor program. The aim of this program is to help you improve your basic mathmatical skills.
 ze:  * 94
Please input your answer.
```

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>   
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the math tutor program. The aim of this program is to help you improve your basic mathmatical skills.\n";
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    const int MAX_RANDOM_INTEGER = 100;
    const int MIN_RANDOM_INTEGER = 0;

    int firstNumber = 0;
    int secondNumber = 0;
    int typeOfProblem = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    typeOfProblem = (rand() % (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    firstNumber = (rand() % (MAX_RANDOM_INTEGER - MIN_RANDOM_INTEGER + 1)) + MIN_RANDOM_INTEGER;
    secondNumber = (rand() % (MAX_RANDOM_INTEGER - MIN_RANDOM_INTEGER + 1)) + MIN_RANDOM_INTEGER;


    if (typeOfProblem == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n" + firstNumber << " + " << secondNumber;
        cout << "\nPlease input your answer. \n";
        cout << firstNumber + secondNumber + "\n";
        cin >> answer;

        if ((firstNumber + secondNumber) == answer)
        {
            cout << "Congrats, thats the right answer!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Whoops, that's not the right answer. Practice more!";
        }
    }
    else if (typeOfProblem == 2)
    {
        cout <<"\n" + firstNumber << " - " << secondNumber;
        cout << "\nPlease input your answer. \n";
        cout << firstNumber - secondNumber + "\n";
        cin >> answer;
        if (firstNumber - secondNumber == answer)
        {
            cout << "Congrats, thats the right answer!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Whoops, that's not the right answer. Practice more!";
        }
    }
    else if (typeOfProblem == 3)
    {
        cout << "\n" + firstNumber << " * " << secondNumber;
        cout << "\nPlease input your answer. \n";
        cout << firstNumber * secondNumber + "\n";
        cin >> answer;
        if (firstNumber * secondNumber == answer)
        {
            cout << "Congrats, thats the right answer!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Whoops, that's not the right answer. Practice more!";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the output as text, not as image. `0.0` is a double, not an int.

Comment: Please create a minimum reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: You should probably focus on getting one operation (e.g. addition) working before implementing a random operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "weird stuff" is because you use the plus sign at times when you should be streaming.

For example (there are several places where this applies):

```
cout << firstNumber + secondNumber + "\n";
```

should be

```
cout << firstNumber + secondNumber << "\n";
```

You want to stream the result of adding `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` followed by a newline character. You do not want to add the sum to the address of the string literal then stream whatever weird stuff happens to be there.